# Just installed ubuntu 12.04. Mouse drag and drop not fully functional. Any known bugs?

Tags: mouse, drag-and-drop

If I drag and drop sometimes doesnt work (especially when I move the mouse fast). The thing I'm dragging just stops if I move the mouse fast.

In win7 is fine, so no hardware issues.

Comment: This is not the right place for bug reports; read [Bug reports](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site), [How do I submit a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

Comment: I am not sure it is a bug. It might be fixed with some settings tweak.

Answer (score 0):

You're using to much processing power when moving them around all quick like that, this isn't windows, don't treat it as such. You can't do that kinda thing on linux, any linux distro, you just gotta slow it down and move them at normal speeds. #calmdownthereflash xD

Comment: I have used ubuntu since 7.10, It was never this bad.